# Create a pause inside a while loop in Javascript

Tags: javascript, while-loop, dom-events

I would like to create a pause inside a `while` loop so that I can create `n` animations that each appear 3 seconds after the other.

I've tried the following, but it doesn't work. Would love to have someone show me what I'm doing wrong.

```
i=0;
while (i < n) {
    someanimation();
    setTimeout(function(){
        i++;
    }, 3000);
     
};
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I add a delay in a JavaScript loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3583724/how-do-i-add-a-delay-in-a-javascript-loop)

Answer (score 45, accepted):

`setTimeout` does not pause; it asks Javascript to run some other code later.

Googling for "setTimeout loop" tells you exactly what you need to know. If you look around a little bit, it even mentions setInterval. The difference: using setTimeout to loop will wait 3 seconds in between loops, whereas setInterval will make it take 3 seconds total for the loop (including however much time the animation takes, as long as it's less than 3 seconds :) ). Also, setInterval constructs an infinite loop that you'll have to break out of after the desired number of times; setTimeout requires you to construct the loop yourself.

```
i = 0;

// setTimeout approach
function animation_loop() {
  someAnimation();
  setTimeout(function() {
    i++;
    if (i < n) {
      animation_loop();
    }
  }, 3000);
};
animation_loop();

// setInterval approach
i = 0;
someAnimation();
iid = setInterval(function() {
  i++;
  if (i < n) {
    someAnimation();
  } else {
    clearInterval(iid);
  }
}, 3000);
```

Comment: you rock!! thank you so much - I'm a real beginner, so I'm not familiar with the idioms and I don't always know what are the best keywords to google. Anyway, you really unblocked me in a big way!!

Comment: This answer introduces an infinite `setInterval`. I'ts better to clear the `setInterval` when `i >= n`.

Comment: @A1rPun agreed; I updated the code to include that (and a bit clearer labelling of what's going on).

Answer (score 11):

`setTimeout` is a little trickier than that because it doesn't block (i.e. it doesn't finish waiting on the timeout before continuing with the program).

What you want is closer to this:

```
var i = 0;
function nextFrame() {
    if(i < n) {
        someanimation();
        i++;
        // Continue the loop in 3s
        setTimeout(nextFrame, 3000);
    }
}
// Start the loop
setTimeout(nextFrame, 0);
```

It may also be worth your while to read up on `setInterval` as a possible alternative.

Answer (score 9):

Well, thanks to ES6-7 with Promises we can now make a pause and make it look nice at the same time!

```
var id = 0;

async function do() {
  while(true) {
    await pause(id);
    //will happen only after pause is done
    id++; 
  }
}
function pause(id) {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(() => {
    console.log(`pause ${id} is over`);
    resolve();
  }, 1500)); 
}

do();
```

Answer (score 5):

One of the way of doing it is to use RxJS. Please take a look at [working example here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38000744/30038)

```
Rx.Observable
  .interval(1000)
  .take(10)
  .subscribe((x) => console.log(x))
```

Answer (score 1):

create a function like:

```
function sleep_until (seconds) {
   var max_sec = new Date().getTime();
   while (new Date() < max_sec + seconds * 1000) {}
    return true;
}
```

and then change your code to

```
i=0;
while (i < n) {
    someanimation();
    sleep_until(3);
    do_someotheranimation();
};
```

Comment: blocking the js was precisely what i happened to be looking for.

Comment: Sometimes you do want to block the engine.. (hopefully just for testing)

Answer (score 0):

You are not very specific about what you want to do, but I'd say the main problem is that you call `someanimation()` without a delay. So maybe this solves it for you:

```
for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    setTimeout(someanimation, 3000 * i);
};
```

Note the missing `()` after `someanimation` as it is the callback for `setTimeout()`.

Comment: Please don't reinvent something for which there are standard idioms.

Comment: @Karl Knechtel: what are you talking about? What "standard idioms"? Yours is the same idea. The only difference is that you launch the next call to `someanimation()` in the timer function.

Comment: "...you launch the next call to someanimation() in the timer function." That's exactly what the standard idiom is. That way, only one callback is enqueued at a time.

Comment: This will enqueue all of the iterations at the same time and then wait 3 seconds to dump out the calls to someanimation at the same time.

Comment: @BrettMathe You do understand how a for-loop works? So there is no way that all calls to `someanimation()` are performed at the same time. While Karl's comment make sense, yours is invalid.

Comment: I thought it was obvious but what I meant by "at the same time" is relative and effectively the same time if someanimation is doing something trivial.  I guess what I should say is that your code does not wait 3 seconds before calling each iteration of someanimation.  Try it yourself and see.

Comment: @BrettMathe \*sigh\* https://jsfiddle.net/fw4mmgca/ Just watch the timestamp. And please get your facts straight, before you downvote the next time.

Comment: Nah seems more like a hack because you're actually enqueuing them all at the same time, just at increasing intervals (3 seconds, then 6 seconds, then 9 seconds...). It's gross.

Answer (score 0):

```
function myFunction() {
    var x;
for(var i=0;i<10;i++){
    if (confirm("Press a button!") == true) {
        x = "You pressed OK!";
    } else {
        x = "You pressed Cancel!";
    }
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;
}
}``
```