# How to create pause or delay in FOR loop?

Tags: javascript, jquery, for-loop

I am working on a website, where I need to create a pause or delay.
So please tell me How to create pause or delay in `for` loop in `javascript` or `jQuery`

This is a test example

```
 var s = document.getElementById("div1");
 for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
     s.innerHTML = s.innerHTML + i.toString();
     //create a pause of 2 seconds.
  }
```

Comment: You cannot "pause" JavaScript in a web browser. You can, however, setup timers and cause code to be executed at a later point with the `setTimeout()` and `setInterval()` APIs available in all browsers.

Comment: tldr: You have to convert the code to recursive, continuation passing style if you want to take advantage of asynchonicity. (Well, that or use a clever trick like Guffa did)

Comment: Similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4548034/create-a-pause-inside-a-while-loop-in-javascript

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I add a delay in a JavaScript loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3583724/how-do-i-add-a-delay-in-a-javascript-loop)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried all one, but I think this code is better one, it is very simple code.

```
var s = document.getElementById("div1");
var i = 0;
setInterval(function () {s.innerHTML = s.innerHTML + i.toString();  i++;}, 2000);
```

Answer (score 29):

You can't use a delay in the function, because then the change that you do to the element would not show up until you exit the function.

Use the `setTimeout` to run pieces of code at a later time:

```
var s = document.getElementById("div1");
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {

  // create a closure to preserve the value of "i"
  (function(i){

    window.setTimeout(function(){
      s.innerHTML = s.innerHTML + i.toString();
    }, i * 2000);

  }(i));

}
```

Comment: @Pointy: Good point. I added a closure to preserve each value.

Comment: @Guffa: Your brackets are off in your function execution

Comment: @BrokenGlass: No, they are not. The code runs just fine. http://jsfiddle.net/Guffa/PcuxY/

Comment: I'm a bit confused, if the closure "preserves the value of `i`" why isn't what's calculated by `i * 2000` equal to `0` as `0` is the first value of `i`? Or, if `i` is being incremented on each iteration, why is the duration between each `innerHTML` update not increased likewise?

Comment: it is even more confusing when I log at the first line of the loop and the first line of the iife: they both log` 0-9` immediately. i know it has been a long time, but can you explain a bit what is going on here? http://jsbin.com/foqineciva/edit?html,js,output

Answer (score 8):

```
var wonderfulFunction = function(i) {
   var s = document.getElementById("div1"); //you could pass this element as a parameter as well
   i = i || 0;
   if(i < 10) {
      s.innerHTML = s.innerHTML + i.toString();

      i++;
      //create a pause of 2 seconds.
      setTimeout(function() { wonderfulFunction(i) }, 2000);          
   }
}

//first call
wonderfulFunction(); //or wonderfulFunction(0);
```

You can't pause javascript code, the whole language is made to work with events, the solution I provided let's you execute the function with some delay, but the execution never stops.

Comment: This will have a big problem because all the timeout funtions share the same "i" value.  They'll all pass 11 to "wonderfulFunction".

Comment: What's the `for` loop for? Given it always executes the `break` wouldn't it be more straightforward to use an `if` statement? For the same reason, I don't see why you need the inner function...

Comment: @nnnnnn Because I edited the answer without thinking. I took a different approach at first an then I changed it to use the clousure. The way is written the `for` is useless, edit time :).

Comment: I'm sorry, my JS syntax isn't the best. What does the line `i = i || 0;` mean?

Comment: @VictorResnov it means "assign `i` to itself if the value of `i` is truthy, otherwise assign it to 0" https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy

Answer (score 2):

if you want to  create pause or delay in FOR loop,the only real method is

```
while (true) {
    if( new Date()-startTime >= 2000) {
        break;
    }
}
```

the startTime is the time before you run the while 
but this method will cause the browsers become very slow

Answer (score 0):

It is impossible to directly pause a Javascript function within a `for` loop then later resume at that point.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you should do it

```
var i = 0;
setTimeout(function() {
   s.innerHTML = s.innerHTML + i.toString();
   i++;
},2000);
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code is an example of pseudo-multithreading that you can do in JS, it's roughly an example of how you can delay each iteration of a loop:

```
var counter = 0;

// A single iteration of your loop
// log the current value of counter as an example
// then wait before doing the next iteration
function printCounter() {
    console.log(counter);
    counter++;
    if (counter < 10)
        setTimeout(printCounter, 1000);
}

// Start the loop    
printCounter();
```

Answer (score 0):

While several of the other answers would work, I find the code to be less elegant. The [Frame.js](https://github.com/bishopZ/Frame.js) library was designed to solve this problem exactly. Using Frame you could do it like this:

```
var s = document.getElementById("div1");
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
   Frame(2000, function(callback){ // each iteration would pause by 2 secs
      s.innerHTML = s.innerHTML + i.toString();
      callback();
   }); 
}
Frame.start();
```

In this case, it is nearly the same as the examples that use setTimeout, but Frame offers a lot of advantages, especially if the you are trying to do multiple or nested timeouts, or have a larger JS application that the timeouts need to work within.

Comment: Isnt the exactly the same as using setTimeout(function(){ alert('Foo'); },2000);

Answer (score 0):

I am executing a function where I need access to the outside object properties.  So, the closure in [Guffa](https://stackoverflow.com/users/69083/guffa) solution doesn't work for me.  I found a variation of [nicosantangelo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/437049/nicosantangelo) solution by simply wrapping the setTimeout in an if statement so it doesn't run forever.

```
    var i = 0;
    function test(){

        rootObj.arrayOfObj[i].someFunction();
        i++;
        if( i < rootObj.arrayOfObj.length ){
            setTimeout(test, 50 ); //50ms delay
        }

    }
    test();
```

Answer (score 0):

The way I found was to simply use `setInterval()` to loop instead. Here's my code example :

```
var i = 0;
var inte = setInterval(() => {
    doSomething();

    if (i == 9) clearInterval(inte);
    i++;
}, 1000);

function doSomething() {
    console.log(i);
};
```

This loops from 0 to 9 waiting 1 second in between each iteration.

Output :

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to **pause** a loop. However you can **delay** the execution of code fragments with the setTimeout() function. It would not make a lot of sense to pause the entire execution anyway.

Comment: "It would not make a lot of sense to pause the entire execution anyway" - Says who? It might not be common, but there are legitimate reasons why you might want to do this.

Answer (score 0):

I am using while loop and check the pause variable to check the user pause/resume the code.

```js
var pause = false;
(async () => {
  for (let index = 0; index < 1000; index++) {
    while (pause) {
      await new Promise((res) => setTimeout(res, 1000));
      console.log("waiting");
    }
    await new Promise((res) => setTimeout(res, 1000));
    console.log(index);
  }
})();

const pausefunc = async () => {
  pause = true;
};
const playfunc = () => {
  pause = false;
};
```

```html
    <button onclick="playfunc()">Play</button>
    <button onclick="pausefunc()">Pause</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pause within loops using async and await. Here is an example.
Carry out your actions in the area above the await line (console log in the example)

```js
async function yay() {
  for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    // actions here
    console.log(i);

    await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 1000));
  }
};

yay();
```

Answer (score -1):

I used a do...while loop to put a delay in my code for a modal dialog that was closing too quickly.

```
your stuff....

var tNow = Date.now();
var dateDiff = 0;
do {
    dateDiff = Date.now() - tNow;
} while (dateDiff < 1000); //milliseconds - 2000 = 2 seconds

your stuff....
```