# How can user break JS loop with a button

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

How a user can stop a loop by clicking a button

Here what I need to do in my loop :

HTML :

```
<input type="button" id="stop" value="Stop" />
<input type="button" id="go" value="Go" />
<div id="div"> </div>
```

Javascript :

```
document.getElementById('go').addEventListener('click', function(){
    // request to server that return a list of object.

  // for each returned objet, I do another request to the server. like that
  for(let i=0; i < objets.length; i++){
    // request to the server.
    // update the div for progress bar like 1%..2%
  }

});

document.getElementById('stop').addEventListener('click', function(){
    // how to break the loop made by go button
});
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Implementing a pause and resume mechanism for javascript loop execution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26696717/implementing-a-pause-and-resume-mechanism-for-javascript-loop-execution)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're running a simple `for (..)` loop, this cannot be stopped via external influence. Everything is happening on the same thread in Javascript, unless your code "ends" at some point and returns control to the browser for a while no UI interaction can happen. The easiest way to have a "loop" is via a `setTimeout` or `setInterval`:

```
interval = null;

startBTN.onclick = function () {
    var i = 0;
    interval = setInterval(function () {
        console.log(i++);  // this is inside your loop
    }, 1);
};

stopBTN.onclick = function () {
    clearInterval(interval);
};
```