# JQuery code getting executed before it reaches there

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, settimeout

I am trying to highlight each menu items after 1 sec gap.
It works fine, but I am facing a problem for the last menu item. I added
`$(strtemp).removeClass("change");` for clearing the last menu item, but that line is getting executed before the `setInterval` function gets executed. I am not able to understand why?

**my.js**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".parent").click(function(){
        str = "li:nth-child(";
        strtemp="";
        i=1;
        var refreshID=setInterval(function(){
            str1=str.concat(i);
            str1=str1.concat(")");
            str2=str.concat(i-1);
            str2=str2.concat(")");
            if($(str2).hasClass("change")){
                $(str2).removeClass("change");
            }
            $(str1).addClass( "change" );
            if(i==10){ 
                strtemp=str1;clearInterval(refreshID);
            }
            i++;
        }, 1000);
        $(strtemp).removeClass("change");
    });
});
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css"/>
        <script type="text/Javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
        <script src="my.js"></script>
        <title>My Jquery</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="parent">
            <ol>
                <li>AAAAA</li>
                <li>AAAAA</li>
                <li>AAAAA</li>
                <li>AAAAA</li>
                <li>AAAAA</li>
                <li>AAAAA</li>
                <li>AAAAA</li>
                <li>AAAAA</li>
                <li>AAAAA</li>
                <li>AAAAA</li>
            </ol>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**stylesheet.css**

```
.parent{
    background-color: yellow;
    height:200px;
    width:400px;    
}

.change{
    border: 1px dotted green;
    background-color: red;
    height:15px;
    width:100px;
}
```

Comment: This is expected behaviour, not sure what you are expecting. If you want this piece of code to be called once interval callback is fired, then set it inside interval callback. Or used named function and call it before the first interval callback is fired

Comment: If you want last item class removal - increase counter to 11? However, maybe there could be simpler solution for desired behavior...

Answer (score 1):

The `$(strtemp).removeClass` call is *outside* the callback function passed to `setInterval`. The code inside the function will execute each tick, everything outside will be executed sequentially when the click handler fires.

**Edit**

Are you looking for something like: http://jsfiddle.net/qprjqy2n/ ?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".parent").click(function(){
        str = "li:nth-child(";
        strtemp="";
        i=1;
        var refreshID=setInterval(function(){
            str1=str.concat(i);
            str1=str1.concat(")");
            str2=str.concat(i-1);
            str2=str2.concat(")");
            if($(str2).hasClass("change")){
                $(str2).removeClass("change");
            }
            $(str1).addClass( "change" );
            if(i==11){ 
                strtemp=str1;clearInterval(refreshID);
                $(strtemp).removeClass("change");
            }
            i++;
        }, 100);
    });
});
```

I would be interested to know what your overall goal is as there would almost certainly be a more straightforward approach.

Answer (score 1):

You can do with also as:

```
function atlast(strtemp)
{
    $(strtemp).removeClass("change");
}


$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".parent").click(function(){
        str = "li:nth-child(";
        strtemp="";
        i=1;
        var refreshID=setInterval(function(){
            str1=str.concat(i);
            str1=str1.concat(")");
            str2=str.concat(i-1);
            str2=str2.concat(")");
            if($(str2).hasClass("change")){
                $(str2).removeClass("change");
            }
            $(str1).addClass( "change" );
            if(i==10){ 
                strtemp=str1;clearInterval(refreshID);
                atlast(strtemp);
            }
            i++;
        }, 1000);

    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

As a suggestion, much easier approach:

```
    $(".parent").click(function() {
     lis = $(this).find('li');

     i = -1;

     inter = setInterval(function() {
       if (i < lis.length - 1) {
         i++;
         $(lis[i - 1]).removeClass('change');
         $(lis[i]).addClass('change');
         console.log($(lis[i]).text() + '_________________' + i);
       } else {

         console.log('end');
         $(lis[i]).removeClass('change');
         clearInterval(inter);
       }

     }, 1000);

   });
```

without building of css selectors, and corrected timer, and fiddle link... http://jsfiddle.net/Lb6v334a/1/

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it as below

```
 var index=1; 
  var curretInterval;
$(".parent").click(function(){
    clearInterval(curretInterval);
    curretInterval=setInterval(function(){
            $("ol li:nth-child("+(index-1)+")").removeClass("change");
            $("ol li:nth-child("+index+")").addClass("change");
            index=index+1;
            index=index>11?1:index;
        },1000);

 });
```

JSFiddle for the same is 
http://jsfiddle.net/prasadFiddle/405cnu39/23/

and on next clicks if you want to start highlighting from begining then http://jsfiddle.net/prasadFiddle/405cnu39/24/

If you want to run this loop only once then http://jsfiddle.net/prasadFiddle/405cnu39/25/

Answer (score 0):

You can use nested `setTimeout` functions, the answer below is inspired from this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4548034/create-a-pause-inside-a-while-loop-in-javascript) post ..

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".parent").click(function(){
    items = $(this).find('li');
    i = -1;
    len = items.length; 
    function animation_loop() {
            $(items[i]).addClass('change');
            setTimeout(function(){ 
            $(items[i]).removeClass('change');
            }, 100  );
        setTimeout(function() { 
            if (i < len) 
        {
            i++;
            animation_loop(); 

        } 

    }, 100);
    };
    animation_loop();
  });
});
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/qprjqy2n/1/)