# Trying to run a while loop for a specified amount of time...Not exiting

Tags: javascript, while-loop, timer, infinite-loop

So, I have a localhost website where you can press a button to start a while loop.  My intent is to loop through this while loop and "wait" for button clicks from the additional buttons, until 135 seconds have passed.  Then, it is supposed to exit the loop.  When the code (which is embedded in html) is executed, it only gets to printing "test1", while failing to leave the loop and print test2.

```
        allyTrack = 0;
        scaleTrack = 0;
        enemyTrack = 0;

        allyString = ""
        scaleString = ""
        enemyString = ""

        allyClicked = false;
        scaleClicked = false;
        enemyClicked = false;

        function allyAdd(){
            allyClicked = true;
        }

        function scaleAdd(){
            scaleClicked = true;
        }

        function enemyAdd(){
            enemyClicked = true;
        }

        //Making the long vectors
        function startGame(){
            var startTime = new Date().getTime();
            //var currentTime = new Date().getTime();
            while(true){
                document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = 'test1';
                if(allyClicked){
                    allyTrack += 1;
                    allyString.append(allyTrack.toString())
                    allyClicked = false;
                }
                else if(scaleClicked){
                    scaleTrack += 1;
                    scaleString.append(scaleTrack.toString())
                    scaleClicked = false;
                }
                else if(enemyClicked){
                    enemyTrack += 1;
                    enemyString.append(enemyTrack.toString())
                    enemyClicked = false;
                }
                else{
                    allyString.append(allyTrack.toString())
                    scaleString.append(scaleTrack.toString())
                    enemyString.append(enemyTrack.toString())               
                }
                currentTime = new Date().getTime();

                if(currentTime-startTime > 2000){
                    break;
                }
            }
            document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = 'test2';
            document.getElementById('list').innerHTML = allyString + '\n' + scaleString + '\n' + enemyString;
        }
```

Comment: The JavaScript engine will only evaluate one section of your code at a time (single-threaded). Functions like `allyAdd()` cannot be called until `startGame()` and its `while` loop have finished. Adding a delay between iterations can allow the engine moments to evaluate other code. – [Create a pause inside a while loop in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4548034/create-a-pause-inside-a-while-loop-in-javascript)

Comment: As long as the loop is running, there are no click events. They get delayed until after the loop has finished. You are just freezing your page.

Comment: @JonathanLonowski So if I create pauses inside will it automatically allow time to respond to button clicks.  Or would the button clicks have to line up with the pauses?

Comment: @RileyFitzpatrick The click events will be run in between the next two iterations of the timeout, so the user shouldn't have to necessarily click during the pauses. Each click event and timeout will be added to a queue, which the engine just works through one at a time (event loop).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the global `setTimeout` method:

```js
function loop(callback, interval) {
  return setTimeout(function() {
    callback();
  }, +interval);
}

loop(function() {
  console.log("Looping...");
}, 1000);
```

Comment: Thank you!  I'm trying this out along with Juan's tip.

Comment: My pleasure! `;D`

Comment: I figured I would do my own research before asking you, but I'm still having trouble understanding the "callback" function.  I'm a new programmer so I haven't learned functional programming yet.  Is there any super quick way to explain `callback();`  Thanks

Comment: In JavaScript you can reference a function: writing its name without parentheses. As you can see, is a way to interact with a function the same way an object would be.

Answer (score 3):

String.append() doesn't belong to JavaScript. I replaced it with [concat()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_concat_string.asp) and now works.

Comment: And I also recommend using the @bukharim96 tip, because while the loop is working the interface remains unresponsive.

Comment: Perfect!  The loop now works.  The only issue is that the site basically freezes up and I cannot press buttons during the period of time where the loop is running.  Any tips so that it can "listen" for button clicks while looping/until time is up?

Comment: Oops didn't see your comment above^^

Comment: Note that `.concat()` doesn't change the string it's called on. It returns a modified string, which should be assigned to a variable.

Comment: @JonathanLonowski Would that create an issue?  Is there a better way?

Comment: @RileyFitzpatrick It's fine. String values are immutable in JavaScript, so they can't actually be altered in-place. You'll always get a new string value when you try to modify them.

Comment: For comprehension shake, instead of `aString.concat(otherString);`, it's `aString = aString.concat(otherString);`